# Based on below code, why I do not need to list the element of map, just use 'line_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(2002, 2013))'

Tags: python, list

```
import pygal line_chart = pygal.Line() 
fx = [None, None,0, 16.6, 25, 31, 36.4, 45.5, 46.3, 42.8, 37.1]
ch = [None, None, None, None, None, None, 0, 3.9, 10.8, 23.8, 35.3] 
ie = [85.8, 84.6, 84.7, 74.5, 66, 58.6, 54.7, 44.8, 36.2, 26.6, 20.1] 
line_chart.title = 'Browser usage (in %)' 
line_chart.x_title='Year' 
line_chart.y_title='%' 
line_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(2002, 2013)) 
line_chart.add('Firefox', fx) line_chart.add('Chrome', ch) 
line_chart.add('IE', ie) line_chart.render_to_file('line.svg')
```

This is my code. In line 9 I know if I put `line_chart.x_labels = list(map(str, range(2002, 2013)))` it can work.

But I do not know why it still works without `list(map())`.

How does `map()` work? Would you help me explain the function 'map'? And show the other examples about map without using list.

Answer (score 1):

The map function applies a given function to each item of an iterable, such as a `list`, and returns an iterator that produces the results. In simple terms, it maps each element of the iterable to a new value based on the function you provide. It's often used for simple transformations of data.

For example, in your case, you're using `map(str, range(2002, 2013))` to convert each integer in the range from 2002 to 2012 into a string. It's not strictly necessary to use `list(map(...))` in your code because `line_chart.x_labels` is expecting an iterable, and map already returns an iterable in Python 3.

Here's how map works:

We can use map to convert a list of integers to strings, as follows:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
strings = map(str, numbers)
```

`strings` is now an iterator containing `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

Similarly, you can convert the iterator to a list if needed. For example:

```
strings_list = list(strings)
```

`strings_list` is now a list containing `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

I hope this helps.